# Zimjs pressmove event doesn't work outer the elements

Tags: javascript, touch, createjs, easeljs

I'm using [zimjs](https://zimjs.com/) library for my canvas project. I'm trying to do continued pressing around the circles. When pressing and moving over the circles, circles must be change color. But pressmove event don't start outer the circles. You need to start to press over the circle. if I start pressing over the circle, the other circle is not affected.

**Here is zimjs events:**

https://zimjs.com/tips.html (See Events)

**What do I want approximately?**

https://zimjs.com/intro/index.html (See drag to eraser example. I want like this but without eraser. Only single pressing)

**Note:** I can't use mouse events. They didn't work on phone touchs.

See snippet:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>ZIM Frame - Outside Template</title>


        <script src="https://zimjs.org/cdn/1.3.0/createjs.js"></script>
        <script src="https://zimjs.org/cdn/10.9.0/zim.js"></script>
        <!-- use zimjs.com/distill for minified individual functions! -->

        <script>
            var scaling = "fit"; // this will resize to fit inside the screen dimensions
            var width = 600;
            var height = 400;
            var color = white; // or any HTML color such as "violet" or "#333333"
            var outerColor = light;

            var frame = new Frame(scaling, width, height, color, outerColor);
            frame.on("ready", function() {

                var stage = frame.stage;
                var circle1 = new Circle(20, "red").pos(100,40, stage)
                var circle2 = new Circle(20, "blue").pos(200,40, stage)
                circle1.on("pressmove", () => {
                    circle1.color = "green"
                    stage.update()
                    console.log("Circle - 1 || Circles pressmove doesn't work when pressing start the outside")
                })
                circle2.on("pressmove", () => {
                    circle2.color = "green"
                    stage.update()
                    console.log("Circle - 2 || Circles pressmove doesn't work when pressing start the outside")
                })

                var button = new Button(140, 100, "reset", grey, dark).center(stage).tap(() => {
                    circle1.color = "red"
                    circle2.color = "blue"
                    stage.update()
                })
                new Label("Pressmove can be start anywhere", 16).pos(0, 300)
                new Label("When pressing and moving over the circles,", 16).pos(0, 320)
                new Label("circles must be select and change color,", 16).pos(0, 340)
                stage.on("pressmove", () => console.log("Stage !!. Stage pressmove doesn't work when pressing outside the circles"))
                stage.update();

            }); // end of ready
        </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the pressmove event only works as you press on an object and move.  If you want to start the press off the object or indeed anywhere then you use stage.on("stagemousedown", function);  Mouse events DO work on mobile they are triggered by a touch so you do not even have to think of it.  There is also "stagemousemove" and "stagemouseup".  Objects on the stage get "mousedown", "presssmove", "pressup", "mouseover", "mouseout", etc. Usually we would change color on "mouseover" and change back on "mouseout" - ZIM has hov() that will do that.  Or a Button() and Label() have built in backgroundColor and rollBackgroundColor.

If you really need to press anywhere before activating a change of color you could do something like this to remember the mousedown stage in general:

```
let mousedown = false;
stage.on("stagemousedown", ()=>{mousedown=true});
stage.on("stagemouseup", ()=>{mousedown=false});    
const circle = new Circle().center();
circle.on("mouseover", ()=>{
   if (mousedown) {
       circle.color = red;
       stage.update();
   }    
});
```

Or you could specifically add a stagemousemove event inside a stagemousedown event and remove it in a stagemouseup event to get the equivalent to a stage pressmove event. The pressmove event was created to help with dragging objects and usually, we do not drag the stage.

Hope this helps and apologies for the delay - you are welcome to join us at https://zimjs.com/slack for discussion!  Cheers.